# Using Firebase, React and Server Side Rendering

Tags: firebase

I'm building a project with react and firebase, with an node express server.  What's the best way to handle routes that need to retrieve the auth status of the user?  If I understand correctly firebase doesn't store its auth data in a cookie, so I'm not sure I'll be able to know the logged in user or even if a user is logged in at all, when on the server.

Comment: So I saw the updates from Google IO.  Is this problem easier to accomplish with the authentication changes that are being released?

Comment: Firebase only provides a CDN-like static hosting environment. It doesn't provide you with servers for server side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase client side, just use the firebase Js library. You may let your server know about the use using id tokens.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with React Redux is that everything is stored in state. When you login , it stores it in state and being passed from Actions to Reducers to the components.

Actions:

```
export function login(email,password){
    return dispatch => auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}

export function logout(){
    return dispatch => auth.signOut();
}

export function createAccount(email, password){
    return dispatch => auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```